# How to post multiple form values to single mysql database column

Tags: php, mysql, row, sql-insert

I need to post the text box values from street_num, and street_name to one column and one row in database and city, state, zip, zip4 values to another column but same row in the database. The database name and table name is "mlsentries". Any help with this will be much appreciated.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="table-align-right">Street Number :</td>
                        <td width="50%"><input name="street_num" type="text" class="textbox" id="street_num" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="table-align-right">Street Name :</td>
                        <td width="50%"><input name="street_name" type="text" class="textbox" id="street_name" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="table-align-right">City :</td>
                        <td width="50%"><input name="city" type="text" class="textbox" id="city" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="table-align-right">State :</td>
                        <td width="50%"><input name="state" type="text" class="textbox" id="state" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="table-align-right">Zip :</td>
                        <td width="50%"><input name="zip" type="text" class="textbox" id="zip" />
                          + 4
                          <input name="zip4" type="text" class="textbox" id="zip4" size="10" maxlength="4" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="50%" class="table-align-right">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO, this would work:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mlsentries SET field1 = ?, field2 = ?';
$fields = array(
$_POST['street_num'] . ' ' . $_POST['street_name'],
$_POST['city'] . ", " . $_POST['state'] . "  " . $_POST['zip'] . "-" . $_POST['zip4'],
);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($fields);
```

and eliminates SQL injection and issues with apostrophes in the input data.

Comment: Thank you i'll give it a shot tomorrow.